# Change instance state to OUT_OF_SERVICE with spring cloud netflix (Eureka)

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

A spring cloud application is documented to have the following endpoints:

> /pause and /resume for calling the Lifecycle methods (stop() and start() on the ApplicationContext)

I suspected that this would be the way in which an instance was marked as OUT_OF_SERVICE in eureka, given the code in *EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration*, a spring class which implements *SmartLifecycle*:

```
@Override
public void stop() {
    log.info("Unregistering application " + this.instanceConfig.getAppname()
            + " with eureka with status OUT_OF_SERVICE");
    if (ApplicationInfoManager.getInstance().getInfo() != null) {
        ApplicationInfoManager.getInstance().setInstanceStatus(
                InstanceStatus.OUT_OF_SERVICE);
    }
    this.running.set(false);
}
```

However, when I POST to the /pause endpoint, I get a 200 response code back (with the value 'true'), but the above code is never executed.

Perhaps I'm not understanding something.  If so, how can I trigger the above code to take an instance out of service?

(The *close()* method of the *EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration* class is called when I shut down the instance - which results in the instance being unregistered - but I'm looking to temporarily suspend service to this instance)

Comment: File an issue for an enhancement. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/377